# how do i make sure usernames is not duplicated in flickr API ? Then print them in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flickr

I'm in an internship in a small company and I'm only new to jQuery. I've been given this task to work on, where I have to parse the photographer's name from Flickr API and print the user name in a list and also make sure there are no duplications. 
This is what I have so far,

```
var list = $("<ul></ul>");// This creates and unordered list.
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, set){
  var link = $("<li/>").attr("ownername", set.owner).text(set.ownername);
  var li = $("<li/>").append(link);
  $(list).append(li);
  $("#flickr-users").append(list);
});
var seen = {};
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
console.log(seen); //it shows in the console all usernames which are true and they aren't duplicated
```

So I'm just struggling to print the names on the HTML file with all the usernames which are set to true.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [jQuery Unique](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

with 1 line of code you sort and remove duplidates:

```
var myArray = <your array>;


var  myUniquesArray =jQuery.unique( myArray );
```

EDIT:

here is a demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/BHqBZ/)

EDIT 2:

to merge all your arrays into one array, you can use

```
jQuery.merge(first, second);
```

it returns a *third* array with **all** the values from *first* and *second*

so what you do is basically go over all of your arrays and merge them into your final array:

see another demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/BHqBZ/2/)

Comment: thanks for the sugestion but it doesnt seem to work, ive created and empty array. Then i push all the usernames that i get from the json and store it there. I then use the unique method but it doesnt seem to do anything when i try to print it in the console.

var nameArray = [];

$(link).each(function(){
        nameArray.push($(this).text());
        var uniqueName =jQuery.unique(nameArray);
        console.log(uniqueName);
      });
@Banana

Comment: you got it a bit wrong my friend, the `.unique()` function returns an array with unique items. i updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Ok so my problem is im looking through the text and getting every username but im storing it in an array but its not stored in one array which causes the problem 

["Cesar Pics"] 
["superkimbo"] 
["Cesar Pics"] 
["Cesar Pics"] 
["Cesar Pics"] 
["Cesar Pics"] 
["superkimbo"] 
["superkimbo"]
how would i store everything in one array ?

sorry I'm rally bad at this.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but i was having more trouble with the arrays so at the end i went a different way about doing it.